# Set up *only* module configuration page

Tags: hooks, routes

I have a custom module that has a settings page.  Problem is, something about my hook_menu settings is also putting a link to this page in the main admin menu (along with Dashboard, Content, etc).

How do I keep my settings page without seeing the main menu item?

```
  // admin config option
  $items['admin/configuration/content/brd_contact'] = array (  
     'title' => t('BRD Contact Form'),
     'description' => t('Configuration options for the BRD Contact Form module.'),
     'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
     'page arguments' => array ('brd_contact_admin'),
     'access arguments' => array('administer brd_contact'),
     'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM    
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove the link from the admin menu altogether, you just need to change the `type` to something other than `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`. [`MENU_CALLBACK`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_CALLBACK/7) is the standard for this type of thing:

```
$items['admin/configuration/content/brd_contact'] = array (  
  'title' => t('BRD Contact Form'),
  'description' => t('Configuration options for the BRD Contact Form module.'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array ('brd_contact_admin'),
  'access arguments' => array('administer brd_contact'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);
```

After you clear Drupal's caches the link should be gone from the admin menu.

If instead you want to move the link from the top level of the menu into the sub-menu under 'Configuration', then you just need to change the string 'configuration' to 'config' in your path, to match the other system menu paths:

```
$items['admin/config/content/brd_contact'] = array (...
```

You'll need to clear the caches before that'll take effect too.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried this already, but I hadn't been flushing the caches.  This time I flushed them and the menu item was still there.  So I used drush to `pm-disable` and `pm-uninstall` my module and when I reinstalled it the menu item was gone and I had my config link on the modules page.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh also, I like the idea of having the config settings for my module show up under the Configuration page, but when I changed the system path to `/admin/config/..` the config link on the module page broke (it just pointed to `/admin`.  Not important enough for me to fight with though.